# How to style the container of material-ui-dropzone

Tags: material-ui, dropzone

I am trying to style the container of material ui dropzone. The documentation says that it needs a prop named dropzoneClass which will recieve a string. But i can't do it anyway. Is there anyone who have faced the problem. A solution is required. Thanks in advance.